# Evaluate $\int\frac{dx}{(a+b\cos(x))^2},(a>b)$

Tags: calculus, integration, indefinite-integrals

Evaluate $$\int\frac{dx}{(a+b\cos(x))^2},(a>b)$$

> I tried to write 1 in numerator as $p'(x)(a+b\cos(x))-p(x)(a+b \cos(x))'$,making something like quotient rule but did not get after that.

Comment: This isn't a pretty integral.  You should probably use Weierstrass substitution.

Comment: Define $$\begin{aligned} I(a) & = \int \frac{1}{a+b\cos{x}}\;{dx} = \frac{4}{{\sqrt{a^2-b^2}}}\tan^{-1}\bigg(\frac{\sqrt{a-b}}{\sqrt{a+b}}~\tan^2(\frac{1}{2}x) \bigg)\end{aligned}$$

Since $\displaystyle I'(a) = -\int \frac{1}{(a+b\cos{x})^2}\;{dx}$ the answer is (given by calculating)

$$ \displaystyle - \frac{d}{da}\bigg[\frac{4}{{\sqrt{a^2-b^2}}}\tan^{-1}\bigg(\frac{\sqrt{a-b}}{\sqrt{a+b}}~\tan^2(\frac{1}{2}x) \bigg)\bigg] $$

Comment: In my comment above, it should be $2$  (not $4$) in the numerator.

Comment: Some useful recommendation on meta: [How to search on this site?](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/29265) You will find a few older posts on this integral both [using SearchOnMath](https://www.searchonmath.com/result?query=$%7B%5Cint%20%5Cfrac%7B%5Cmathrm%20dx%7D%7B(a%2Bb%5Ccos%20x)%5E2%7D%7D$) and [using Approach0](https://approach0.xyz/search/?q=%24%5Cint%20%5Cfrac%7B%5Cmathrm%20dx%7D%7B(a%2Bb%5Ccos%20x)%5E2%7D%24&p=1).

Comment: For example: [Better way to evaluate $\int \frac{dx}{\left (a +b\cos x \right)^2}$](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1887194),
[I need help with this integral: $ \int \frac{1}{(a+b \cos x)^{2}} \, \mathrm dx $?](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3180841),
[Evaluate $\int\frac{dx}{(a+b\cos(x))^2},(a>b)$](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3747649)..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$$I=\int \frac{dx}{(a+b\cos x)^2} \\=\int\frac{dx}{\left(a+b\cdot \frac{1-\tan^2 \frac x2}{1+\tan^2 \frac x2} \right)^2}\\=\int\frac{1+\tan^2 \frac x2}{\left(a(1+\tan^2 \frac x2) +b(1-\tan^2\frac x2)\right)^2} \sec^2\frac x2 \ dx \\ \overset{t=\tan \frac x2}=2\int\frac{1+t^2}{\left[(a-b)t^2 +a+b\right]^2} dt$$ Use partial fractions to break this down into $$ \underbrace{\frac{1}{a-b}\int \frac{dt}{(a-b)t^2 +a+b} }_{I_1} -\underbrace{\frac{2b}{a-b}\int\frac{dt}{\left((a-b)t^2 +a+b\right)^2}}_{I_2}$$ $I_1$ is easy to evaluate (use the arctan function). For $I_2$, substitute $t^2=\frac{a+b}{a-b}\tan^2y$, which results in a massive simplification: $$I_2 =\frac{1}{(a+b)\sqrt{a^2-b^2}}\int \cos^2y \ dy $$ Hopefully you can take it from here.